# Get average with nested relationship belongs to in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to ask for you. hopefully my problem will be quickly resolved.

I have 3 tables consist of :

ads

- id
- title_ads

transaction

- id
- transaction_id
- id_ads

rating

- id
- transaction_id
- rating_value

relationship :

ads to transaction is has many

transaction to rating is belongs to

I want to ask this, how to get avg rating value from table ads? I am confused, because I think to get avg rating maybe use hasManyThrought but in this case, There is relationship belongsTo. hwo to solved it? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define a `hasManyThrough` relation in your `Ad` model

```
class Ad extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all ratings of an Ad.
     */
    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Rating', 'App\Transaction');
    }
}
```

Now you can get the ratings in your controller with the `Ad` model and the `ratings` relation

```
public function getRatingsAverage()
{
    // Fetch a single ad (or remove the find and get multiple)
    $ad = Ad::where('id', 1)->with('ratings')->get();

    // write average logic here...

    // could be something like this:
    $total_rating = 0;

    foreach($ad->ratings as $rating) {
        // loop through all the ratings of the ad and add the value to the total rating
        $total_rating = $total_rating + $rating->value;
    }

    // divide the total rating by the amount of ratings to get the average
    $average = $total_rating / count($ad->ratings);
}
```

Comment: can I hasManyThrough with relationship belongsTo?

Comment: It's either hasManyThrough, or belongsTo. Not both. You can make another relation with an other model, yes.

Comment: Op wanted to get the average from the table. Not on the server side `avg rating value from table ads`

Answer (score -1):

To get to your ratings for each ad you can query the ads by eager loading the relationships. Then you can access the transactions and the ratings by looping through the `$ads` and add you average logic.

```
$ads = Ads::with('transaction.rating')->get();
//Load all ads with the transaction and rating relations
foreach($ads as $ad){
    //All transactions from the ad
    $transactions = $ad->transaction;
    foreach($transactions as $transaction){
        //The rating from the transaction
        $rating = $transaction->rating;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548145/get-average-with-nested-relationship-belongs-to-in-laravel#comment94995001_44548331